# grep error unrecognized option

Tags: bash, mysql, grep

Any attempt to use grep on my system results in this:

```
grep: unrecognized option '--skip-triggers'
Usage: grep [OPTION]... PATTERN [FILE]...
Try 'grep --help' for more information.
```

I can't find anywhere that this skip-triggers option exists in .bashrc, .profile, or $GREP_OPTIONS.  "type grep" says

```
grep is aliased to `grep --color=auto'
```

Obviously there is no --skip-triggers option in grep, but there is in mysql so my hypothesis is that somehow in grepping through mysql data I have got this bit cached somewhere in a hidden file. And normally I would do something like

```
grep -R skip-triggers *
```

but I can't due to the error.  >.<

Also this first appeared simultaneously with an upgrade from ubuntu 14.04 to 16.04.  I am assuming that is unrelated but I'm not sure.

All suggestions are welcome.

Comment: What happens if you use `/bin/grep`?

Comment: You could boot from a Live USB system and execute the `grep` from there.

Comment: You could also try running `type -a grep`

Comment: @heemayl - same result.

Comment: @wjandrea - 
grep is aliased to `grep --color=auto'
grep is /bin/grep

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone else needs to know:  Inspired by @Jos answer, I loaded up a virtualbox running windows and searched for the skip-triggers text.  Turns out there was a file named "--skip-triggers" containing mysql output.  I deleted that file and all is well.  Thanks.